# operators as classmethod in python 2 vs. 3

Tags: python

I understand that you can overload operators as classmethods using metaclasses:

```
class _Two(type):
    def __add__(self, other):
        return (2 + other)

class Two(object):
    __metaclass__ = _Two

Two + 3 # 5
```

It works in Python 2.7.6 but fails in 3.4.0 with this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'type' and 'int'
```

Why is that?

You could do it in a way compatible with both versions like this however:

```
class _Two(type):
    def __add__(self, other):
        return (2 + other)

class Two(_Two('', (object,), {})): pass

Two + 3 # 5
```

I get why the second version works but to my eye it's doing essentially the same as the first one, so what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way of using metaclasses in Python3 is:

```
class Two(metaclass=_Two):
    ...
```

That is, there's nothing special about adding `__metaclass__` as a class attribute in Python3. You're getting the same error as you'd see if you wrote:

```
>>> class Two(object):
        this_does_nothing_special = _Two
>>> Two + 3
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'type' and 'int'
```

Comment: Also note that [six](https://pythonhosted.org/six/#six.with_metaclass) has utilities to make this quite easy :-)

Comment: OK, the explanation is as easy as I feared it would be. :)